# How to bundle Angularjs and jQuery npm modules and customized libraries with Browserify and Gulp?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, gulp, browserify, browserify-shim

I'm working on a single-page app that uses multiple external dependencies. The app is mostly built with Angular 1. I'm implementing some performance critical parts of the app using React and ES6 syntax. I have rewritten all the app files using ES6 modules syntax, for example:

myComponent.js

```
let Component = {
    bindings: {
        binding: '<'
    },
    controller: controller
};

// @ngInject
function controller() {
    var vm = this;
}

export default Component;
```

index.js

```
import angular from 'angular';

let module = angular.module('app', []);

import Component from './myComponent';
module.component('myComponent', Component);

export default module;
```

However, there's still legacy code that depends on Angular, jQuery and other libraries. To bundle the code, I'm using Gulp and Browserify with some transformers. I'm also splitting the code into two bundles: bundle.js and vendor.js. The former one is for the application logic, whereas the latter one consists of several npm modules plus a dozen of custom libraries located in the libs directory. Some of the custom libraries require either angular or jquery.

I'm able to generate both bundles: bundle.js containing all the application code, and the vendor.js containing all the required npm modules and custom libraries. However, the issue is that when I try to run the application on a browser, I get multiple 'Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined' and 'Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined' which point to the custom libraries in vendor.js. I guess the reason is that only npm modules are getting browserified and shimmed and then merged with the custom libraries.

All ideas of how to bundle and shim the vendor scripts properly are welcome.

Below are stripped versions of both package.json and Gulpfile.js

package.json

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [
        "babelify"
      ],
      [
        "browserify-shim"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "jQuery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "angular": "./node_modules/angular/angular.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jQuery": "global:jQuery",
    "angular": "global:angular"
  }
```

Gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');

var babelify = require('babelify'),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    buffer = require('vinyl-buffer'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    sourceMaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    watchify = require('watchify'),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
    ngannotate = require('browserify-ngannotate'),
    stream = require('merge-stream');

var globalShim = require('browserify-global-shim').configure({
    'jQuery': 'jQuery',
    'angular': 'angular'
});

var config = {
    js: {
        src: './app/app.js',
        libs: './app/libs/**/*.js',
        outputDir: './dist/',
        mapDir: './',
        appOutputFile: 'bundle.js',
        vendorOutputFile: 'vendor.js'
    },
};

var vendors = ['react', 'angular', 'jquery'];

function appBundler(bundler) {
    bundler
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source(config.js.src))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(rename(config.js.appOutputFile))
        .pipe(sourceMaps.init({
            loadMaps: true
        }))
        .pipe(sourceMaps.write(config.js.mapDir))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.js.outputDir));
}

gulp.task('build:app', function() {
    var bundler = browserify({
            entries: config.js.src,
            debug: true
        })
        .external(vendors)
        .transform(babelify)
        .transform(globalShim)
        .transform('browserify-ngannotate')

    appBundler(bundler);
})

function vendorBundler(bundler) {
    return bundler
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('vendor.js'));
}

var customLibsStream = gulp.src(config.js.libs);

gulp.task('build:vendor', function() {
    var bundler = browserify({
            debug: true
        })
        .require(vendors)
        .transform(globalShim);

    stream(vendorBundler(bundler), customLibsStream)
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(rename(config.js.vendorOutputFile))
        .pipe(sourceMaps.init({
            loadMaps: true
        }))
        .pipe(sourceMaps.write(config.js.mapDir))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.js.outputDir));
})
```

Comment: the best solution will be USE WEBPACK please ^^

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to do that? angular, jquery and other vendor scripts  are big libraries that doesn't change -as far as you use the same version-, while your bundle is likely to change a lot. So, whenever you make a little change in any script, your bundle changes, invalidating browser cache. Usually, I believe, to serve vendor scripts separately is better because of browser caching, while bundle small, application logic scripts is better to prevent too much concurrent requests.  Also, certain vendor libs like jQueryUI really works bad when shimmed as npm modules.

Comment: I'm going to have two bundles; one for vendor scripts which are changed rarely; and the app bundle which contains the application code. When developing, I would only be watching the app bundle. However, at the moment, I'm not able to bundle the vendor bundle correctly.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and add the require statement you're using in your gulpfile? at least the ones that shows up in the 'build:vendor' task. So your problem is more easily reproducible.

Comment: Can it be that your vendor bundle is just adding vendors as modules, but not setting them as a `window`object? 

Maybe you can just set up a `vendor-origin.js` as a browserify entry that just requires vendor dependencies and attach them to window like: 
`window.jQuery = require('jQuery');`

Comment: Tried to create a `vendor-origin.js` file with a single line `window.jQuery = require('jQuery');` and set that as a entry point of the vendor bundle. But the errors still persist.

Comment: Maybe some of those vendor libs need window/global access. You are using browserify with gulp, meaning things got too complex. Can't you leave legacy code still using script tags approach, and use browserify only for the newer extensions? Anything outside the browserify build still be visible, however there are plenty of libs that simply doesn't work well in a modularized world.